# react components. asking Question for react.js error

Tags: reactjs

what is the meaning of this error?

Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:3000/logo192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)

Comment: check if the image exists or not before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a [manifest.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) file in your app. From MDN:

> Web app manifests are part of a collection of web technologies called progressive web apps (PWAs), which are websites that can be installed to a device's homescreen without an app store. Unlike regular web apps with simple homescreen links or bookmarks, PWAs can be downloaded in advance and can work offline, as well as use regular Web APIs.

This file will contain a bunch of information, including urls to one of more image files. One of these files will be `logo192.png` which does not exist in your app (or isn't accessible by the web server).

Either add the file, or remove the reference.